# Error cannot find module 'sequelize'

Tags: node.js, npm, sequelize.js

I've install (fresh install) using nodejs and npm, then install sequelize-cli and module as per instruction on tutorial of sequelize http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/migrations.html#installing-cli

But when wan't to do anything with sequelize, it return an error like below :

```
    me@u64:~/project/manztihagi$ sequelize
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'sequelize'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/sequelize-cli/lib/helpers/model-helper.js:7:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/sequelize-cli/lib/helpers/index.js:18:52
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/sequelize-cli/lib/helpers/index.js:17:4)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/sequelize-cli/lib/commands/init.js:7:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
me@u64:~/project/manztihagi$
```

Search another solution until reinstall the packages still not luck.

How to resolve this error ?

```
me@u64:~/project/manztihagi$ ng -v

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 6.1.3
Node: 10.9.0
OS: linux x64
Angular: undefined
... 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.7.3 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         0.7.3 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   0.7.3 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          0.7.3 (cli-only)
@schematics/update           0.7.3 (cli-only)
rxjs                         6.2.2

me@u64:~/project/manztihagi$ node -v
v10.9.0
me@u64:~/project/manztihagi$ npm -v
6.2.0
me@u64:~/project/manztihagi$
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like you install the cli in global node modules. You should also install the `sequelize` package along with `sequelize-cli`

if do it globally

```
npm install -g sequelize-cli
npm install -g sequelize
```

if do it locally

```
npm install --save sequelize-cli
npm install --save sequelize
```

Hope it can solve your issue

Comment: I'm already try your solution and solve my issue, but the other hand, from the other tutorial that guide the sequelize-cli shall install as global module and sequelize as local module but the error appear.

I'm trying on other machine, sequelize-cli as global and sequelize as local both of sequelize can run well ...

Not sure what happened on my this machines error

Answer (score 4):

```
Error: Cannot find module 'sequelize'
```

I had the same problem, but it was caused by wrong name of module.

- **correct form is: require('sequelize')**
- wrong is: require('**S**equelize')

I was working on windows and trying to run code on better system ;)

hope this might be helpfull, GL

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar error:

`Error: Cannot find module 'sequelize/types/lib/operators'`

which I found was caused by my Visual Studio Code 'helping out' by adding in:

`const { substring } = require("sequelize/types/lib/operators");`

I deleted this line from the top of my code, and problem went away.

Since google sent me to this similar question, I thought I would share my different solution to a different problem:

What happened?

Visual Studio Code tries to help out by automatically adding `imports` as you type, and when I typed this line of code:

`enumSingular = enumPlural.substring(0, enumPlural.length - 1);`

VS Code thought it needed to add the `substring` from Sequelize. I was trying to use the substring() method of the JavaScript String prototype, but I did not notice the auto-add.

Comment: Yes you were right! VS code was the culprit. It has added an import to something which i accidently typed and deleted. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should install `sequelize` and `sequelize-cli` with same option. 
Ex:

`npm install -g sequelize-cli
npm install -g sequelize`

GL.